# Query always return all the data

Tags: mysql, sql

Why MySQL query always returns all column data from the table?:

```
SELECT column 
  FROM table 
 WHERE column = "+"
```

The column type is VARCHAR.

Comment: MySQL will cast all non-numeric strings to zero, and the comparison to integer zero will be true. Post sample data, and we can validate this for certain.

Comment: SELECT ''+'' returns 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the result of \`select 'a'=0;\` 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300120/why-is-the-result-of-select-a-0-1)

Comment: Ok, you need to make up your mind about what your query really is ('0' or '+'). If you're getting all results with `'+'` then we need to see sample data. That is suspect.

Comment: I have this result only with two pairs of single quotes '' and ''

Comment: Those are pairs of single quotes, not double quotes?

Comment: [**If one of the below answer resolve your question, kindly mark it as the right answer, see how here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after clarifying your query, it's a little clearer what has happened. In MySQL, `+` is a numeric operator only, not a concatenation operator.  Non-numeric strings will always cast to zero, so if you attempt to "add" together two empty strings (pairs of single quotes), you are effectively selecting `0 + 0`.

```
MySQL> SELECT 1 + 1, '' + '', '1abc' + 1;
+-------+---------+------------+
| 1 + 1 | '' + '' | '1abc' + 1 |
+-------+---------+------------+
|     2 |       0 |          2 |
+-------+---------+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And since non-numeric strings cast to zero, any non-numeric string in your column will match the condition effectively as

```
WHERE column = 0
```

Example comparing zero to a numeric and non-numeric string:

```
MySQL> SELECT 'abcd' = 0, '1234' = 0;
+------------+------------+
| 'abcd' = 0 | '1234' = 0 |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          0 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, I already understand, but why MySQL returns all column data if there are no matched values?

Comment: @IgorKhromov No, it doesn't return all if none are matched. The point is that _all strings_ which are non-numeric will evaluate to 0 when cast as integers. When you compare against integer `0` in the `WHERE` clause, they are all cast to integers, and all match 0.  If you had any strings like `1a` in your column, they would cast to their correct integer values and _not_ match the zero,.

Answer (score 1):

Because you compare with `0` (an integer), the column value is converted to integer before the comparison. All those values will therefor be `0`, unless they contain a string that can be typecasted to a different integer value (like `'1'`).

To solve it, try:

```
WHERE column = '0'
```

Comment: thanks, I understand that it can't compare INT and VARCHAR and column=0 always TRUE. Thanks to all you, guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

MySql on comparing a varchar with an integer, tries to cast the varchar into an integer. And if the string is not a number, it is by default cast into the integer 0 and hence returns true on comparison with 0. If there was a column as "123" for example, it wouldn't be selected.